# How to distinct a list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Is there a way to do follow because I can't find any solution.

I have a array with objects, each object in this array has a x and y position and a text field like so:

```
[{x: 100, y: 100, text: "hello"},
 {x: 100, y: 100, text: "this is another message"},
 {x: 50, y: 25, text: "message on another place"}]
```

Now I try to get a new list of objects where each position is unique and all the message will be a new array of text.

So I try to get a final list like:

```
[{x: 100, y: 100, text: ["hello", "this is another message"]},
 {x: 50, y: 25, text: [message on another place]}]
```

I tried a couple of approaches found on the internet without success.

Comment: What did you try, exactly?

Comment: In your final result you have invalid syntax for inner objects.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Typical use of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @laruiss I try to create a new list with new objects, check in the new list if the x, y positions already exist if not create new object otherwise to append but how to append it.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry but you are correct, changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to group the array into an object using the concatenated value of x and y as the key. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
let arr = [{"x":100,"y":100,"text":"hello"},{"x":100,"y":100,"text":"this is another message"},{"x":50,"y":25,"text":"message on another place"}]

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, {x,y,text}) => {
  let k = x + '_' + y;
  c[k] = c[k] || {x,y,text: []};
  c[k].text.push(text);
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer I didn't know what I did wrong

Comment: Happy to help :) You can post your code if you want. I can help you check it out.